# Duplicate resources for different flavors in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

My `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 { ... }
    flovor2 { ... }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = [ ... ]
        jniLibs.srcDirs = [ ... ]
    }
    flavor1 {
        res.srcDirs 'path to flavor1 res'
        debug.assets.srcDirs 'path to flavor1 debug assets'
        release.assets.srcDirs 'path to flavor1 release assets'
    }
    flavor2 {
        res.srcDirs 'path to flavor2 res'
        debug.assets.srcDirs 'path to flavor2 debug assets'
        release.assets.srcDirs 'path to flavor2 release assets'
    }
}
```

Assets folders for both flavors have the same structure and contain files with the same names.

When trying to build I've got `Duplicate resources` error for *every file* I have in assets folder.

Why gradle takes into account assets in a folder, that belongs to another flavor? Any ideas how to fix the issue?